# Fit, AIC and deviation of my generalized linear model (poisson)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, fitting, poisson-regression

I need to fit a GLM (generalized linear model) in **R**, something like

```
model <- glm(Daily.Results ~ sqrt.of.Clicks + Days + log.of.Clicks * sqrt.of.Days, family = poisson)
```

which relates

> Daily.Results = variable that I need to count (and predict)
>
> Clicks = counts clicks in a link (which drives a person to be a potencial buyer)
>
> sqrt.of.Clicks = square root of Clicks
>
> log.of.Clicks = natural logarithm of Clicks
>
> Days = 1, 2, 3... sqrt.of.Days = square root of 1, 2, 3...

in a dataset with **14 rows/observations**

and `family = poisson` because `Daily.Results` are non negative integers, with log link-function

The results of `summary(model)` are:

```
Call:
glm(formula = Daily.Results ~ sqrt.of.Clicks + Days + log.of.Clicks * 
    sqrt.of.Days, family = "poisson")

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.24096  -0.61927  -0.09041   0.81640   2.45392

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                120.88890   22.33723   5.412 6.23e-08 ***
sqrt.of.Clicks               0.27487    0.07698   3.571 0.000356 ***
Days                         0.35892    0.09334   3.845 0.000120 ***
log.of.Clicks              -15.84863    3.20527  -4.945 7.63e-07 ***
sqrt.of.Days               -23.43680    4.22029  -5.553 2.80e-08 ***
log.of.Clicks:sqrt.of.Days   2.66063    0.47141   5.644 1.66e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 499.316  on 13  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  23.706  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 141.81

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The model above is the one which have the minimal AIC and Residual deviance (after some data transformation tentatives / log and sqrt of the data)

1. I do not know very well how good or bad can be this model. By
   now, I often read people saying here that lower AIC and residual
   deviance means better fit. Is this correct **and enough**?
2. Also, would be nice to know which value can be considered **lower
   enough** (*R squared is so far more friendly*). Can you help me with
   that?
3. A really good fit can lead to bad predictions? Can you give **some example**?
4. The diagnostic plots of my regression (`plot(model)`) follows, and I could not tell if some visual information can be found there. Perhaps, evidence of errors that I don't realized.

[Residuals vs Fitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWGG2.jpg)

[Normal Q-Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN5y4.jpg)

[Scale-Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzagt.jpg)

[Residuals vs Leverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EwKj.jpg)

[Cook's distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqBoG.jpg)

[Cook's distance vs Leverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIpfj.jpg)

I think that a final and clean answer about this questions will help a lot of people here. Straight to the point.

Comment: You have a large number of wide-ranging questions here. That doesn't lend itself to "a final and clean answer" that is "straight to the point". You might want to search the site & read a number of existing threads that overlap these topics. It may take a bit to get the information you want, but you would learn much in the process. Either way, you should probably trim this down to a single, answerable question. Then follow this up w/ a new question as the 1st is answered. You can always link back for context, if appropriate.

Comment: @gung I looked already. But I'll try something else.

Comment: Eg, for #3, you seem to be referring to [tag:overfitting], for #2 [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/486/)  might be helpful, [here's a related search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=[aic]%20is%3aquestion%20lowest). Re #1, if people here already say this, what are you hoping for from the answer to this thread? What do you mean by "enough"?

Comment: @gung Thanks for the links. I'll read carefully. About #1, I'll reformulate that later (if the question keeps unsolved).

Comment: That's a good path forward, @Andre. I appreciate your being open minded about this. We'll see how it goes.